# How to implode an array and display the values with "x" amount of digits?

Tags: php

I want to display each value of the array with 4 digits; if the value has less than 4 digits it has to be padded with leading zeros.

```
<?php 
$x = array(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024);
echo implode(", ",$x) . "<br>";
echo sprintf("%04s", implode(", ",$x)) . "<br>";
?>
```

If I run that code; it will output:

```
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024
```

all I want is to figure out how to output this:

```
0001, 0002, 0004, 0008, 0016, 0032, 0064, 0128, 0256, 0512, 1024
```

Comment: If i do that; i will only get the first value "0001"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want format each array element, [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is probally the best option to go as it applies a callback for each elements of the given array.

```
$x = array(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024);

$formatted = array_map(function ($n) { return sprintf("%04s", $n); }, $x);

print_r($formatted);
```

Comment: Might add a little description or summary.

Comment: `%04d` would be ideal, rather than `%04s`.

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> I want to display [each value of the array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with 4 digits; if the value has less than 4 digits it has to be [padded with leading zeros](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php).

Let's translate your question into code:

```
$x = array(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024);
echo(
    implode(', ',
        array_map(                     // each value of... -----------------+
            function ($value) {        //                                   |
                return str_pad(                     // padded               |
                    $value, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT    // with leading zeros   |
                );                                  //                      |
            },                         //                                   |
            $x                         // <----------- ... the array -------+
        )
    )
);
```

[`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) can also be used (as you have tried). However, if the values from your array are numbers it's probably better to use the `%d` format specifier:

```
function ($value) {
    return sprintf('%04d', $value);
}
```